# Align max & min percent changes in a geom_bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am not sure if this is possible in `ggplot` or not, but I have been tinkering with this for quite some time and am unable to figure it out.

I am trying to create a plot that mimics this layout:
[image]

I am pretty sure I have my data formatted correctly. This is what I have done so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(lubridate)

rental.data.melted <- melt(rental_data)

rental.data.melted <- rental.data.melted %>%
  slice(217:10908)

rental.data.melted <- rental.data.melted %>%
  rename(date = variable)

rental.data.melted$date <- lubridate::ym(rental.data.melted$date)

rental.one.year <- rental.data.melted %>%
  filter(year(date) >= 2021 & month(date) >= 3)

rental.one.year <- rental.one.year %>%
  group_by(RegionName) %>%
  mutate(prev_rent = lag(value),
         pct.chg = (value / prev_rent - 1) * 100)

one.year.results <- rental.one.year %>%
  filter(year(date) == 2022)

one.year.results <- one.year.results %>%
  filter(RegionName %in% c("Daytona Beach, FL", "Miami-Fort Lauderdale, FL", "Lakeland, FL", "New York, NY",
                           "North Port-Sarasota-Bradenton, FL", "Syracuse, NY", "Tulsa, OK", "McAllen, TX"))
```

The resulting data frame looks like this:

```
> as.tibble(one.year.results)
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  RegionName                        date       value prev_rent pct.chg
  <chr>                             <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 New York, NY                      2022-03-01  2934      2804   4.64 
2 Miami-Fort Lauderdale, FL         2022-03-01  2832      2699   4.93 
3 Tulsa, OK                         2022-03-01  1286      1294  -0.618
4 McAllen, TX                       2022-03-01  1017      1020  -0.294
5 North Port-Sarasota-Bradenton, FL 2022-03-01  2402      2488  -3.46 
6 Syracuse, NY                      2022-03-01  1318      1334  -1.20 
7 Lakeland, FL                      2022-03-01  1808      1725   4.81 
8 Daytona Beach, FL                 2022-03-01  1766      1680   5.12
```

As for the plotting, this is what I am working with so far but I cannot figure out how to get the bars "aligned" like in the example above so that the metro area with the biggest decrease (North Port-Sarasota, FL) is aligned with the metro with the largest increase (Daytona Beach, FL):

```
ggplot(data = one.year.results, aes(pct.chg)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(one.year.results, pct.chg > 0),
           aes(y = RegionName), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = subset(one.year.results, pct.chg < 0),
           aes(y = RegionName), stat = "identity")
```

As well, here is the data in the reproducible form:

```
structure(list(RegionName = c("New York, NY", "Miami-Fort Lauderdale, FL", 
"Tulsa, OK", "McAllen, TX", "North Port-Sarasota-Bradenton, FL", 
"Syracuse, NY", "Lakeland, FL", "Daytona Beach, FL"), date = structure(c(19052, 
19052, 19052, 19052, 19052, 19052, 19052, 19052), class = "Date"), 
    value = c(2934, 2832, 1286, 1017, 2402, 1318, 1808, 1766), 
    prev_rent = c(2804, 2699, 1294, 1020, 2488, 1334, 1725, 1680
    ), pct.chg = c(4.63623395149786, 4.92775101889589, -0.618238021638329, 
    -0.294117647058822, -3.45659163987139, -1.19940029985007, 
    4.81159420289856, 5.11904761904762)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), groups = structure(list(
    RegionName = c("Daytona Beach, FL", "Lakeland, FL", "McAllen, TX", 
    "Miami-Fort Lauderdale, FL", "New York, NY", "North Port-Sarasota-Bradenton, FL", 
    "Syracuse, NY", "Tulsa, OK"), .rows = structure(list(8L, 
        7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(
  RegionName = c(
    "New York, NY", "Miami-Fort Lauderdale, FL",
    "Tulsa, OK", "McAllen, TX", "North Port-Sarasota-Bradenton, FL",
    "Syracuse, NY", "Lakeland, FL", "Daytona Beach, FL"
  ), date = structure(c(
    19052,
    19052, 19052, 19052, 19052, 19052, 19052, 19052
  ), class = "Date"),
  value = c(2934, 2832, 1286, 1017, 2402, 1318, 1808, 1766),
  prev_rent = c(2804, 2699, 1294, 1020, 2488, 1334, 1725, 1680), pct.chg = c(
    4.63623395149786, 4.92775101889589, -0.618238021638329,
    -0.294117647058822, -3.45659163987139, -1.19940029985007,
    4.81159420289856, 5.11904761904762
  )
), class = c(
  "grouped_df",
  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), groups = structure(list(
  RegionName = c(
    "Daytona Beach, FL", "Lakeland, FL", "McAllen, TX",
    "Miami-Fort Lauderdale, FL", "New York, NY", "North Port-Sarasota-Bradenton, FL",
    "Syracuse, NY", "Tulsa, OK"
  ), .rows = structure(list(
    8L,
    7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L
  ), ptype = integer(0), class = c(
    "vctrs_list_of",
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"
  ))
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE))

data %>%
  group_by(sign(pct.chg)) %>%
  arrange(-abs(pct.chg)) %>%
  slice(1:3) %>%
  mutate(position = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(position, pct.chg)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_label(aes(label = RegionName)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: That is super helpful! However, is there a reason McAllen, TX (-0.6) and New York, NY (4.6) are removed from the plot? I tried to edit the slice from 1:3 to 1:4 but it doesn't seem to plot correctly.

Comment: Because McAllen is the 4th highest row and only the top 3 are shown. This can be adjusted by changing the line `slice(1:3)`. This changes if you use a dataset other than the one provided

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't catch the edit above where it is now arrange(-abs) ... adding that, plus slice(1:4) fixed it. Perfect! Thanks!